# onValueChange of BasicTextField is not triggered on setting value to TextFieldValue("") in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I want to execute some code when the value of BasicTextfield changes in Jetpack Compose.

Everything works fine in 2 conditions:

- for any value change.
- if all the textfield value is cleared using the device keyboard

But,
When I try to change the state value to empty text on click of a button, using this code :

```
textfieldstate.value = TextFIeldValue("")
```

onValueChange is not triggered.

Although if I set it to any other value, onValueChange is triggered.

```
textfieldstate.value = TextFIeldValue("FOO")
```

Code of Button/Icon click:

```
Icon(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
              textfieldstate.value = TextFieldValue("")
 }) {.....}
```

Is there a way to trigger onValueChange of BasicTextField when value of the field is cleared from an external button click event??

Comment: Can you add more code. I don't get why you using 

 Modifier.clickable {
              textfieldstate.value = TextFieldValue("")
 }

Comment: @ArbenMaloku 
Icon() is what is being used in the behind. And thus Modifier.clickable() is used.
Can't share exact code because of restrictions.
But I can assure that click event is not a concern, because the click event is triggered.
The code is debugged to deduce that onValueChange is not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it all at once as is more recommended, I would do this:

```
@Composable
fun AppContent(
  viewModel: MyViewModel
) {
  val state by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
  MyPanel(
    state = MyViewModel,
    onValueChange = viewModel::onValueChange,
    onClickButton = viewModel::onClickButton
  )
}

@Composable
fun MyPanel(
  state: MyTextFieldState,
  onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
  onClickButton: () -> Unit
) {
   TextField(
    value = state.text,
    onValueChange = onValueChange
   )
   Button(
    onClick = { onClickButton() }
   ) {
    ...
   }
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
  private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(MyUiState())
  val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

  fun onValueChange(str: String) {
    _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(text = str)
  }

  fun onClickButton() {
    _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(text = "")
  }
}

data class MyUiState(
  val text: String = ""
)
```

The code above mainly elevates the state of the TextField, processes all things in the viewModel, and wraps a layer of UI state with a data class. If there are other requirements, you can also add different parameters, for example, if there is an error in the TextField, it can be written as:

```
data class MyUiState(
  val text: String = "",
  val isTextError: Boolean = false
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onValueChange` callback is useful to be informed about the latest state of the text input by users.
If you want to trigger some action when the state of (`textFieldValue`) changes, you can use a side effect like `LaunchedEffect`.

Something like:

```
var textFieldValue by remember() {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("test" ))
}

LaunchedEffect(textFieldValue) {
    //doSomething()
}

BasicTextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = {
        textFieldValue = it
    }
  )

OutlinedButton(
    onClick = { textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy("") }
) {
    Text(text = "Button")
}
```